# Laravel custom path for img tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-7

Hellow.i see an image URL in some websites source like below:

```
<img src="/imageName.jpg">
```

in my project in laravel I code this like below:

```
<img src="{{asset('img/imageName.jpg')}}">
```

but the result in the browser will be like this for src attribute of img tag:

```
src="127.0.0.1:8000/public/img/imageName.jpg"
```

I want to turn it to something like this: `src="/imageName.jpg"`
thanks

Comment: Then you have to run the app from a domain pointing to `127.0.0.1` with a document root of `whatever/path/to/public`.

Comment: you mean run the application with: php artisan whatever/path/to/public --port=8000

Comment: No you need to run it with Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

The assets function is concatenating your application URL, defined in the `app.php` ( under config folder) into your assets path, which are located in `public` folder.

using this method is perfectly fine, as it handles any change in your application URL out of the box.